# Don't ask for mic permission

Tags: ios, webrtc, microphone

I'm developing a WebRTC iOS application to receive video/audio streaming from a webcam.

The device only receives audio and video streams, does not collect audio and video, so do not need to apply for microphone permissions.

How can I prohibit the application of microphone permisson? 
@kemmitorz

I have deleted the following method,but did not solve the problem.

```
- (RTCRtpSender *)createAudioSender 
{ 
    RTCMediaConstraints *constraints = [self defaultMediaAudioConstraints]; 
    RTCAudioSource *source = [_factory audioSourceWithConstraints:constraints]; 
    RTCAudioTrack *track = [_factory audioTrackWithSource:source 
                                                  trackId:kARDAudioTrackId]; 
    RTCRtpSender *sender = [_peerConnection 
                           senderWithKind:kRTCMediaStreamTrackKindAudio 
                                 streamId:kARDMediaStreamId]; 
    sender.track = track; 
    return sender;
 }
```

If I set OfferToReceiveAudio to false. The device will not apply for microphone permission. But the received video has no sound.

```
- (RTCMediaConstraints )defaultOfferConstraints 
{ 
    NSDictionary *mandatoryConstraints = @{ 
                                            @"OfferToReceiveAudio" : @"true", 
                                            @"OfferToReceiveVideo" : @"true" 
                                          };
    RTCMediaConstraints constraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] 
                                 initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints 
                                          optionalConstraints:nil]; 
    return constraints;
 }
```

Comment: did you add permission in info.plist file

Comment: yes, I did it.
If I do not do that, the application will crash.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score -1):

> Recording audio requires explicit permission from the user. The first
>   time your app’s audio session attempts to use an audio input route
>   while using a category that enables recording (see “Audio Session
>   Categories”), the system automatically prompts the user for
>   permission; alternatively, you can call requestRecordPermission: to
>   prompt the user at a time of your choosing

```
switch ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission]) {
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:
        // here call your record method and put this condition in your viewcontroller.
        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:

        break;
    case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
        // This is the initial state before a user has made any choice
        // You can use this spot to request permission here if you want
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Happy Coding..

Any query then tell me.

Comment: I want to disable the microphone permissions dialog because I don‘t need this permission.I don't know which step of webrtc to establish the connection process will apply for microphone permissions.Thanks

Comment: @loveDoudou i think this link will help you . https://www.script-tutorials.com/step-by-step-webrtc/